# Generic factory methods in Typescript with interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a set of interfaces in my Typescript code (autogenerated by OpenAPI Generator) and I would like to implement a generic method something like this:

```
interface Foo {}
function getFoo(id: string): Foo { /* ... */ }

interface Bar {}
function getBar(id: string): Bar { /* ... */ }

function get<T>(type: Type<T>, id: string): T {
    switch(type) {
        case typeof Foo:
            return getFoo(id);
        case typeof Bar:
            return getBar(id);
        default:
            throw "Unknown type";
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

If Foo and Bar were classes, I could have used

```
function get<T>(type: new() => T, id: string): T {
    switch(typeof new type()){
        // ...
    }
}
```

, but this doesn't work with interfaces.

I could tag the interfaces and do

```
interface Foo { type: 'foo'; }
interface Bar { type: 'bar'; }

function get<T>(type: string, id: string): T {
    switch(type) {
        case 'foo':
            return getFoo(id);
        case 'bar':
            return getBar(id);
        default:
            throw "Unknown type";
    }
}
```

, but I don't see a way to preventing something like `get<Bar>('foo', id)`.

Comment: The interfaces **do not exist** at runtime, they're erased in transpilation.

Comment: What even is `Type<T>` supposed to be? How would you use this function?

Comment: Type<T> is supposed to be something like new() => T or perhaps the discriminator from a tagged union type. Just something I can use to both specify the interface and give me type-safety.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdrMQW), where you store an object that maps interface names to interface getter functions?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that does exactly what I was looking for. I don't think I fully understand how the typesystem is deciding the return type of the `get`-function, but I probably just need to look into it some more. If you add your code as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to possibly work, you'd need some mapping between genuine *values*, like the strings `"Foo"` and `"Bar"`, to the corresponding interface *types*, like `Foo` and `Bar`.  You'd pass a value into `get()`, along with an id of some sort, and then get a value of the corresponding interface type.

So, what values should we use? Strings are a good choice since they're easy to come by, and there's a very straightforward way to represent mappings between string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and other types: *object types*.  They are already mappings between keys (of string literal types) and values (or arbitrary types).

For example:

```
interface TypeMapper {
   "Foo": Foo;
   "Bar": Bar;
}
```

Which can equivalently be written

```
interface TypeMapper {
    Foo: Foo;
    Bar: Bar;
}
```

Armed with a type like that, then `get()` should have the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature

```
declare function get<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(
  type: K, id: string
): TypeMapper[K];
```

whereby the `type` input is of type `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof TypeMapper`, and the output is of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `TypeMapper[K]`.

Let's just imagine we already have that implemented, and make sure you could call it as desired:

```
const foo = get("Foo", "abc");
// const foo: Foo
foo.a; // it's a Foo

const bar = get("Bar", "def");
//const bar: Bar
```

Looks good.

---

Now for an implementation of `get()`.  You *could* write it similar to in your question:

```
function get<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(type: K, id: string): TypeMapper[K] {
  switch (type) {
    case 'Foo':
      return getFoo(id); // error! Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'TypeMapper[K]'.
    case 'Bar':
      return getBar(id); // error! Type 'Bar' is not assignable to type 'TypeMapper[K]'.
    default:
      throw "Unknown type";
  }
}
```

This works at runtime, and the typings are correct, but unfortunately the compiler can't verify that.  When you check `type` with `case 'Foo'`, it can narrow down `type` from type `K` to `"Foo"`, but it doesn't know how to narrow the type parameter `K` itself, and so it doesn't see that a value of type `Foo` is assignable to `TypeMapper[K]`.  This is currently a limitation of TypeScript, and there are various open feature requests asking for some improvement.  For example, [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014).  Until and unless such a feature is implemented, you will need to work around the limitation.

The easiest approach is to just suppress the errors with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function get<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(type: K, id: string): TypeMapper[K] {
  switch (type) {
    case 'Foo':
      return getFoo(id) as TypeMapper[K];
    case 'Bar':
      return getBar(id) as TypeMapper[K];
    default:
      throw "Unknown type";
  }
}
```

That works, but now *you* have the responsibility of implementing it properly, since the compiler can't.  If you had swapped `case 'Foo'` with `case 'Bar'`, the compiler wouldn't have noticed:

```
function getTwoBad<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(type: K, id: string): TypeMapper[K] {
  switch (type) {
    case 'Bar': // 
      return getFoo(id) as TypeMapper[K]; // no error
    case 'Foo': // 
      return getBar(id) as TypeMapper[K]; // no error
    default:
      throw "Unknown type";
  }
}
```

So you might want an approach where the compiler actually helps with type safety instead.

---

Another approach is to refactor so that the indexed access *type* corresponds to an actual indexed access.  That is, represent the `TypeMapper` mapping interface as an actual object into which you look up with `type` as the key.  Something like:

```
function get<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(type: K, id: string): TypeMapper[K] {
  const typeMapper: TypeMapper = {
    Foo: getFoo(id),
    Bar: getBar(id)
  }
  return typeMapper[type];
}
```

That works just fine, because the compiler is able to verify that indexing into a value of type `TypeMapper` with a key of type `K` produces a value of type `TypeMapper[K]`.  Hooray!

Except, uh, that `typeMapper` object is going to run `getXXX(id)` for every `XXX` type, all but one of which will be useless calls, at best.  Really we want to refactor so that we look up the `getXXX()` function by `type`, and then call just *that* function with `id`:

```
function get<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(type: K, id: string): TypeMapper[K] {
  const typeMapper: { [P in keyof TypeMapper]: (id: string) => TypeMapper[P] } = {
    Foo: getFoo,
    Bar: getBar
  }
  return typeMapper[type](id);
}
```

Now that really *does* work fine, because you're only calling the correct function.  You could now refactor this... presumably we could use a static `typeMapper` that lives outside of the function and is reused:

```
const typeMapper: { [K in keyof TypeMapper]: (id: string) => TypeMapper[K] } = {
  Foo: getFoo,
  Bar: getBar
}
function get<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(type: K, id: string): TypeMapper[K] {
  return typeMapper[type](id);
}
```

That's just about as far as we can go, except that it seems that instead of defining `TypeMapper`, we should be able to *derive* the `TypeMapper` type from the `typeMapper` value.  I'll spare the detailed explanation, but such a derivation might look like this:

```
const _typeMapper = {
  Foo: getFoo,
  Bar: getBar
}
type TypeMapper = { [K in keyof typeof _typeMapper]: ReturnType<typeof _typeMapper[K]> };
const typeMapper: { [K in keyof TypeMapper]: (id: string) => TypeMapper[K] } = 
  _typeMapper;

function get<K extends keyof TypeMapper>(type: K, id: string): TypeMapper[K] {
  return (typeMapper[type])(id);
}
```

And there you go.  Now every time you add a new interface, you can just add an entry to `_typeMapper`, and everything just works:

```
interface Baz { c: boolean }
declare function getBaz(id: string): Baz;

const _typeMapper = {
  Foo: getFoo,
  Bar: getBar,
  Baz: getBaz, // add this
}

const baz = get("Baz", "ghi");
// const baz: Baz
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIBiB7b6De6SAXOgM5RyQDm6AvqACYwoA2ScGCArhClGGwR01GFBzYAFGEakKVCNQCUpCQG5QoSLESoMAIQ4F0AI1IRuAWxPx6TFu07oefAUJFjDcabPKUaKuheGiCaIBBIljBkAA566ACSEGACSKwAglCwljFQZARh6Oja8Mho6AAqAJ4xMACySDG1cAUgRUUSqrgANKDtQRykXn12oW3OvPyCwqJQAPIQMAA8ANLoMAAesBCM+QDWMFXYCJU19Y3NAHySUGekK93FvvIBpNW1DU3wANorALqtfpkADuKRQAAt0DczkpAf10CgkGQMAByCQo4gjeHoThQbhwGZiCQ+JRqdAAenJ6zgcGwcAAhKdaug0bgUcV8hBsFAiGQyGBqBETKwMFA8LdmSj3ucvnBfn8UQA6LHtRHIlleDEq-q4-GEqBeElkynU2kMpmozUc9BcnlI-mCpDC0Xis4s6WfZrypXa9DMZDcVhQTHjbFQcG04HoABEAFUIHsucDhBKYNGQv0GOMsyMXFN3LMKsDsKt1lsYDt9odjhbPfBrqn7o8ZHJ-IpAh6Lj9-nCiiCwZDobVYfhfWrUeiQ9iirqCR5xLgSbza125f8M-DxxqOFrQ-DZ-rDTJYUiV7L5Rv+v6kIHg76iuHIzH44nsMn0Kn0yqs0Uc+M824+pFtghiMKWmzbLs6AHEcJydrKDZ3OgDxPK2CjKG8Zx1muAKjnu-ZQBCUKpiOY5IpaO6kCagC8G4AjHv3jiYh6vOxLHsu8Feuu6BkeqrLYBiFJUnRDEHvOR6MCe+Qcd2fyXu0163lO06Pm+z4JkmKZnF+e4-qMuaTIB84VBGMDLGsEEVlBME1tJcCIbUTaoX46Edlhq7yr2CJCBQH5ubKmEfKu6AALyeR0uCkLMrESb0e5FF4kWeBwJLfiqompth3yprJIx-kUAHTCx2D4uB5aVtB1ZwX5VxDjAjkts5rxnpxuEqig3k8hlq6kIQ3wAArFMI1lVYFsp-KQPhoQEIWXM1Px9QCdAhWFWARUV2CxdiCViRwqV7ul1U-NlRq5YUNqRNEcTlJgYAAG4YHh-TtRAPldf5xi-INFWwXNcDjVCDUvO2M2-R5S2hY98KdOtm3wttszDDpKoFQWRJ3WZZaQVWP22fZdXIc2zxthhoM9pDOpMXOb1esdx5yXlekgH+Jo3RErCgM9PkAPrU7YEMjNDUU9CM8NJXAsOGAAXolBpIJLsVZqmv3Lb1ayQN9NapjWPOHX9pAAEqUxA0pLFrJw66NLWzXQISc51us9egn3q8Nv3-ZNjXA8Fs22WDy0WzKzQhKAJoo-qpVYxrI2B-WtX1UTLkBTHOEhGH84R5Z2M2brePx1NwOQ6JtWZdlSgnUzYRaNApTxFLxgoKQJi4CKSDCFmzBsBwXAGYVCNyx7QMk1LwcgHbzi4MtsySNGEjRo80ZOig0akiHVJjwga0SKAG-YIqSDGlSKQovkSCrdgYRjyYRihVP0ZeHPMb+svISUpfgwDHAYRX3AiomAfxRQGPkQD+F8OqmDlpPMQ08pYP2jNQcEYBn6ry8i9HkV9pYDElkAA)

Comment: Thank you. That was an amazing answer! Unfortunately I am probably working against the spirit of Typescript by trying to do something like this, but thank you for showing me how it could be done.